# Mysql++ "undefined reference to __imp___ZN7mysqlpp10ConnectionC1Eb"

Tags: c++, mysql, reference, undefined, mysql++

I am trying to install the mysql++ in Code::Blocks, but When I try to run the example code I get this error:

> `undefined reference to __imp___ZN7mysqlpp10ConnectionC1Eb`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: See http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.language/2004-08/0135.html

Comment: I didn't understand what does it means.

Comment: What operating system are you using (I'm guessing Win32)? Are you using mysql++ source or compiled code or an installer package?

Comment: I use win32, I have a directory lib and inside it there is the .dll of the mysql++.
I think that I am not importing the .dll correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build MySQL++ with the exact same compiler and compiler options as you're using to build your program.  What you're seeing is a name mangling and/or ABI mismatch due to mixing compilers and/or build options.  This can be anything from a drastic error like trying to use a Visual C++ DLL with MinGW, to something more subtle like trying to use a MinGW DLL built with g++ 3.4.5 in a program you're building with MinGW g++ 4.4.

Unlike C, C++ doesn't try to preserve binary compatibility between greatly different compilers.

Comment: I'll try to compile it by myself

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to compile by myself :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a linker issue. It could well be that a DLL you need isn't present, or mysql++ was compiled but not correctly linked.